# generate a boost-python reference

Tags: c++, python, boost, documentation, boost-python

Has anybody an idea how can I generate automatically a reference of my declared boost-python methods:

```
 def("foo", foo, args("x", "y"), "foo's docstring")
 def("foo2", foo, args("x", "y"), "foo's docstring")
 def("foo3", foo, args("x", "y"), "foo's docstring")
 def("foo4", foo, args("x", "y"), "foo's docstring")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org). You need to hack it a bit to make functions argument lists prettier, see e.g. what I did for [minieigen](http://www.launchpad.net/minieigen): [boost::python source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~eudoxos/minieigen/trunk/view/head:/minieigen/minieigen.cpp), [sphinx config file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~eudoxos/minieigen/trunk/view/head:/doc/source/conf.py) and [generated docs](http://flux.doxos.eu/minieigen/).

For something along the same line, but more complex, have a look at [Yade](https://www.yade-dem.org/doc/yade.wrapper.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/), the de-facto Python document generator.  There is no need to modify Sphinx.

Sphinx extracts documentation from docstrings, so add docstrings to document your Boost Python module.  Compile it to a shared object (`.so` file) as usual.

Create an `.rst` file for each module.  For example, create `demo.foo.rst` for module `demo.foo`:

```
.. automodule:: demo.foo
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Then, set up and run Sphinx and it will make nice documentation for you in a variety of formats.